# Variation of a integration involving derivatives

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

I'm having problem with calculating the functional derivative of $F$ with respect to $\phi(x)$ while

$$F = \int d^{4}x \phi^2 \partial_{\mu}\phi\partial^{\mu}\phi.$$

I want to obtain $\frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi}$ by making form of $$\delta F = \int d^{4}x \frac{\delta F}{\delta \phi}\delta \phi.$$

But, I am confused how could I compute $\delta F$ because of $\partial_{\mu}\phi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beginning with
$$
F[\phi] = \int d^{4}x \ \phi^2 \ \partial_{\mu}\phi \ \partial^{\mu}\phi
$$

we replace $\phi$ with $\phi+\lambda\eta$:
$$
F[\phi+\lambda\eta] = \int d^{4}x \ (\phi+\lambda\eta)^2 \ \partial_{\mu}(\phi+\lambda\eta) \ \partial^{\mu}(\phi+\lambda\eta)
$$

Then we take the derivative w.r.t. $\lambda$ at $\lambda=0,$ and use integration by parts to remove any derivatives of $\eta$:
$$
\frac{d}{d\lambda} \left. F[\phi+\lambda\eta] \right|_{\lambda=0}
= \int d^{4}x \ \left( 
2\phi\eta \ \partial_{\mu}\phi\ \partial^{\mu}\phi 
+ \phi^2 \ \partial_{\mu}\eta \ \partial^{\mu}\phi 
+ \phi^2 \ \partial_{\mu}\phi \ \partial^{\mu}\eta
\right) \\
= \int d^{4}x \ \left( 
2\phi\eta \ \partial_{\mu}\phi\ \partial^{\mu}\phi 
- \partial_{\mu}(\phi^2\ \partial^{\mu}\phi) \eta
- \partial^{\mu}(\phi^2\ \partial_{\mu}\phi) \eta
\right) \\
= \int d^{4}x \ \left( 
2\phi \ \partial_{\mu}\phi\ \partial^{\mu}\phi 
- \partial_{\mu}(\phi^2\ \partial^{\mu}\phi)
- \partial^{\mu}(\phi^2\ \partial_{\mu}\phi)
\right) \eta \\
$$

The $\eta$-independent factor in front of $\eta$ is now the functional derivative:
$$
\frac{\delta F}{\delta\phi} 
= 2\phi \ \partial_{\mu}\phi\ \partial^{\mu}\phi 
- \partial_{\mu}(\phi^2\ \partial^{\mu}\phi)
- \partial^{\mu}(\phi^2\ \partial_{\mu}\phi) \\
= 2\phi\ \partial_{\mu}\phi\ \partial^{\mu}\phi 
- (2\phi\ \partial_{\mu}\phi\ \partial^{\mu}\phi + \phi^2 \partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\phi)
- (2\phi\ \partial^{\mu}\phi\ \partial_{\mu}\phi + \phi^2\ \partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi) \\
= -2\phi\ \partial^{\mu}\phi\ \partial_{\mu}\phi - \phi^2\ \partial^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\phi
$$

Comment: Thank you. I solved it. You gave me a key : integration by parts :)

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**  When you're doing this variation, you're implicitly replacing $\phi \to \phi + \delta \phi$ and keeping all the terms linear in $\delta \phi$.  So you have
$$
\delta F = \int d^4x \left[ (2 \phi \, \delta \phi) \partial_\mu \phi \partial^\mu \phi + \phi^2 (\partial_\mu \delta \phi) (\partial^\mu \phi) \right].
$$
The first term is of the form $(\text{something}) \times \delta \phi$, but the second one isn't.  So you need to get rid of the derivative on the $\delta \phi$ in the second term, somehow.

Do you know of any mathematical techniques where you can "shift" the derivative on one term in an integrand onto a different term in the integrand?

Comment: That is exactly what I want to know. Thanks, I solved.